# Which Geometry Shape Is $3x^2+3y^2-10y+3=0$

Tags: calculus

$3x^2+3y^2-10y+3=0$

Wolfram says it is a circle, I know a circle is of the form $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$

${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2=0$ is not a circle, it's a point.

Comment: Can you rearrange the equation that you have into the form that you “know” the equation of a circle has? In a similar vein, we “know” that a line is of the form $y=mx+b$, so is $3x+2y-7=0$ the equation of a line or not?

Answer (score 3):

Wolfram is right (of course).

Note that you can write it as (divide by three and write them as squares):

$$x^2+(y-\tfrac{5}{3})^2-\tfrac{25}{9}+1=0$$

and so it's equivalent to

$$x^2+(y-\tfrac{5}{3})^2=(\tfrac{4}{3})^2$$

So yeah. It's a circle.

---

Sidenote; I see that you say a circle is of the form $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=0$; this is not true. A circle is of the form $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=c^2$.